# How to code a compreensive set of commands (class and subclasses?)

Tags: python, class

I will place my question on top, and proceed with the detailed explanation of what I want to achieve below:

**QUESTION:** ***How do I create a subclass such that the parent class recognizes it automatically, without me having to declare it explicitly?***

I am currently developing an API in Python to handle SCPI commands.

The SCPI code I am working on can be seen as having a main command with different subcommands. Example:

```
MODulator:DRiVe
         :DRiVe?
         :AMPlitude
         :AMPlitude?
         :AMPRange?
```

My idea was to write code such that you could do something like:

```
instrument.modulator.drive("?")
instrument.modulator.drive(1)
instrument.modulator.amplitude(?)
```

So, if I understand this correctly, I would have to create a subclass of the "instrument" class. Unfortunately, it provides me with an error:

```
pem.modulador.drive()

AttributeError: 'HindsPEM200' object has no attribute 'modulador'
```

which is understandable. So, how do I create a subclass such that the parent class recognizes it automatically, without me having to declare it explicitly?

My current code is as follows:

```
import pyvisa

class HindsPEM200:
    
    
    def __init__(self,address:str = None,
                     write_termination:str = "\n",
                     read_termination:str = "\n",
                     baudrate:int = 250000,
                     timeout:int = 1000
                     ):
        self.address = address

        # Open PyVISA resource manager and alias it!
        self.rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
        
        self.connection(address = address,
                        write_termination=write_termination,
                        read_termination=read_termination,
                        baudrate=baudrate,
                        timeout=timeout)
        
    def connection(self,
                       address = None,
                       write_termination:str = "\r",
                       read_termination:str = "\r",
                       baudrate:int = 250000,
                       timeout:int = 1000
                       ):
        
        
        
        """ This functions uses PyVISA to initiate communications with the instrument.
        

        Parameters
        ----------
        address : str, optional
            DESCRIPTION. This parameter sets the COM address of the device.
            The default value is None, and it will make the procedure raise an exception
        write_termination : str, optional
            DESCRIPTION. The default is '/n/r'.
        read_termination : str, optional
            DESCRIPTION. The default is '/n/r'.
        baudrate : int, optional
            DESCRIPTION. The default is 250000.
        timeout : int, optional
            DESCRIPTION. The default is 600.

        Returns
        -------
        None."""
        
        if address == None:
            print("ERROR:: No address specified!\n")
        else:
            print(f"::VISA:: Instrument address is {address}\n")
        
        self.hinds_pem = self.rm.open_resource(address)   
        self.hinds_pem.write_termination = write_termination
        self.hinds_pem.read_termination = read_termination
        self.hinds_pem.baud_rate = baudrate
        self.hinds_pem.timeout = timeout
        
        print(f"::VISA:: Connection opened for {address}\n")
               
        return self.hinds_pem
        
    def identification(self):
       
        """" Query the instrument identification string"""
        
        idn_str = self.hinds_pem.query('*IDN?')
        
        print("\n=========================================================")
        print(f"::*IDN?:: Identification Table for {self.address}")
        print("=========================================================")
        print(f"{self.address} is {idn_str}")
        print("=========================================================\n")
        

#################
# :MODulator:DRive(?)
#################

class modulator(HindsPEM200):
    
    def __init__(self):
        HindsPEM200.__init__(self)
        
    def drive(self,args = None):
        input_str = "MODulator:DRIVe?"
        answer = self.hinds_pem.query(input_str)
        print(answer)

###############################################################################
###############################################################################
        
pem = HindsPEM200("ASRL9::INSTR")

pem.identification()

pem.modulador.drive()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I fully understand what your code is doing, but from your explanation it sounds like you want composition instead of inheritance. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) article.
Then your pem could look something like the following:

```py
class HindsPEM200:    
    def __init__(self,
                     modulator: Modulator,
                     address:str = None,
                     write_termination:str = "\n",
                     read_termination:str = "\n",
                     baudrate:int = 250000,
                     timeout:int = 1000
                     ):
        self.modulator = modulator
        ...

class Modulator:
    ...

mod = Modulator()
pem = HindsPEM200(mod, ...)
```

Comment: I just realized that what I wanted are subfunctions...